# How to change Date format in `Jquery mask plugin` from dd/mm/yyyy to mm/yy?

Tags: jquery, datetime, jquery-plugins

I am using `Jquery Mask Plugin` and want to change date format from `dd/mm/yyyy` (00/00/0000) to  `mm/yy` (00/00)?? You can check here. I am using this plugin [Jquery Mask Plugin](http://jquery-plugins.net/maskjs-jquery-plugin-to-mask-inputs) but unable to change format. When i write mm/yyy in place of `00/0000` it show mm/yyyy in textbox and then i can't modified it.

```js
$('.expiration').mask("00/0000", {
  placeholder: "__/____"
});
```

```html
<label for="expiration" class="gfield_label">Expiration (MM/YY)</label>
<div class="ginput_complex">
  <input type="text" class="expiration" id="expiration" name="expiration" tabindex="2" value="" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the mask.js.
I got it working with the following:

```
var options = {
  $el: $('.expiration'),
  mask: "MM/YYYY"
}
Mask.newMask(options)
```

Do pay attention to the uppercase YYYY. The js file seems to be case sensitive.

[github](https://github.com/bguzmanrio/maskjs):
'Any combination of YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm, where:
Y means year
M means month
D means day
H means hour
m means minutes'